# Need to add diagonal cells with an additional cell for each subsequent diagonal

Tags: vba, excel

I need help getting the sum of specific cells in a diagonal format.  My issue is that each subsequent diagonal grows by 1 cell.  I was thinking I use a For loop, but I don't know how to add an additional cell to the summation for each iteration of the loop.  The picture below shows an example of the format the data will be in that I need to sum.  Any ideas?  Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that asks for the range and the count of values to add. You can probably adjust the code to get rid of the need to add count altogether, but it's a start.

Just for clarity, you'd enter into your sheet like this:

```
=AddDiagonal(D4,0)
=AddDiagonal(D7,1)
=AddDiagonal(D10,2)
...
```

**Function**

```
Function AddDiagonal(rng As Range, cnt As Long) As Double

Dim x As Long
Dim answer As Double

For x = 0 To cnt

    If x = 0 Then

        answer = answer + rng.Offset(x, x)

    Else

        answer = answer + rng.Offset(x * -3, x * 1)


    End If

Next

AddDiagonal = answer

End Function
```